# How Are Voronoi Polygons Drawn?

Tags: geometry, intuition, voronoi-diagram

Lately, I have come across an interesting concept in Geometry called **Voronoi Polygons** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Below is an example (using R programming with code from https://r-charts.com/part-whole/voronoi-diagram/) in which we start of with a set of points (in 2 Dimensions) and Voronoi Polygons are drawn around each point:

```
# install.packages("deldir")
library(deldir)

# Data
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(50)
y <- runif(50)

# Calculate Voronoi Tesselation and tiles
tesselation <- deldir(x, y)
tiles <- tile.list(tesselation)

plot(tiles, pch = 19,
     fillcol = hcl.colors(50, "Purple-Yellow"))
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to understand in general - given these points, how exactly are the Voronoi Polygons created?

I have seen videos online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-Ya01iGO0E) that liken this to "soap bubbles forming in a cup of water" - an animation was shown that a small circle is drawn around each point ... and then the circles are expanded in size until they start to collide with each other ... and somehow, this produces a Voronoi Diagram.

But I was hoping to understand this from a more mathematical perspective.

Can someone please help me understand this - **given a set of points, how do exactly do you draw a Voronoi Diagram? Is the Voronoi Diagram for any set of points unique?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram
- https://r-charts.com/part-whole/voronoi-diagram/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-Ya01iGO0E

Comment: Interesting Question : It made me look up some videos & then attracted me to some online tools to play with ! +1 !

Answer (score 2):

Voronoi Diagrams are nothing but assigning a Data Point to every Point in the Plane (2D Case , Illustrative Example)

When we say "assigning a Data Point" , it could be a number or a category or a colour. The Examples I give will use Colour.

The assignment is based on "Closeness" , according to some Distance metric , which can be Euclidean Distance or Manhattan Distance or something else. The Examples I give will use Euclidean Distance which is quite usual.

Using colour & Euclidean Distance will make it easy to visualize the Procedure Intuitively.

Let our Data Points be $P=\{A,B,C,D\}$
We will iteratively & manually add the Points to the Plane. Here is the Initial Colouring , where all Points are assigned to Point $A$ & given colour red :

[image: VA]

When we include Point $B$ , we see that the Perpendicular Bisector of $AB$ is the line which indicates whether a Point on the Plane is closer to $A$ or to $B$.
Hence , we assign Points closer to $B$ the colour blue.

[image: VB]

When we include Point $C$ , we have to check the Perpendicular Bisectors of $AB$ & $BC$ & $AC$ to assign the new colour green.

[image: VC]

When we add in the last Point $D$ , we have to check the Perpendicular Bisectors of $AB$ & $BC$ & $AC$ & $AD$ & $BD$ & $CD$ & assign the new colour orange. Most of the lines at long Distances will not matter , except at the Parts close to the newly added Point.

[image: VD]

We have the Voronoi Diagram for $P$.

Let us say we have a new Point $E$ towards the right.
Same Procedure will give the new colour lavender to Point $E$.

[image: VE]

Calculation & Diagram will change when the new Point $E$ is not at the right , but is at the Centre , like this :

[image: VE]

We can continue this manually , though it will quickly get tough when we have Dozens or Hundreds or Millions of Data Points in $P$.
We can automate it with various tools which will use the Distance metric to "draw" the Perpendicular Bisectors (or something else , suitable for that Distance metric) to generate the Voronoi Diagram.

That was all about Intuition & visualization. Here is the "Semi-formal" Definition from Wolfram [[ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagram.html ]] :

> The partitioning of a plane with n points into convex polygons such that
> each polygon contains exactly one generating point and every point in a
> polygon is closer to its generating point than to any other.

Similarly , this is the "Semi-formal" Definition from Thomas M. Liebling and Lionel Pournin [[ https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-ismp/60_liebling-thomas.pdf ]] :

> A Voronoi diagram induced by a finite set A of sites is
> a decomposition of the plane into possibly unbounded (convex) polygons ,
> each consisting of those points at least as close to some particular site as to the others.

Comment: Here is a video which highlights some of aspects of Voronoi Diagrams [[ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GafRRl5XRPM ]] It is interesting !

Comment: Here is a tool to play with interactively online [[ https://cfbrasz.github.io/Voronoi.html ]] Nice & easy to visualize & great fun !

Comment: You have attempted to have a didactic presentation, but it is too diluted and rigor is lacking. First of all, I don't agree with terms like "semi-formal" definition. Moreover, I think that without mentionning the (dual) Delaunay triangulation you haven't a good understanding of Voronoi diagrams and the efficient algorithm(s) that allow to compute them (one of the questions of the asker)